# SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH undefined

Tags: c, encryption, input

So currently my code looks something like this:

```
int main(){
    char input[1024]
    size_t length;
    unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    fgets(input,1024,stdin);
    length = sizeof(input);
    SHA(input,hash,length)
}
```

I receive a compilation error telling me that `SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH` is undefined. I thought when compiling including `-lssl` and `-lcrypto` would sort of define it for me?

Comment: I think I might have to add #include <openssl/evp.h> and then call OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

Comment: *define it for me*, not that won't **define** it. Those are linker options, and its worth reading about it.

Answer (score 0):

`SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH` is defined in `sha.h`, if you are using openssl, you need to include this header file

Comment: Yea so now I've done #include <openssl/sha.h> but it can't seem to find that. Thanks for answering too!

Comment: it should be at /usr/include/openssl, but if openssl is installed on other non standard location you have search for this file and specify its directory name in -I option in your build

Comment: Yea thanks, I don't think the library was installed. I think it's in the libssl-dev library. Installed that and it seems to work fine. Thanks again! One last thing, when I print out the hash after calling SHA1 should I being getting nonstandard characters?

Comment: You probably have print non-ascii characters, you may print them in hex